# OpenCV iterating through contours

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, opencv3.0

I'm trying to plot all the contours detected in an image with a line, I can access each contour using `cnt = contour[number]` but I can't seem to get any sort of iteration through the array, always getting either

> TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index

When I do `for i in contours:`

or

> ValueError: Too many operands

When I have the bellow code

```
img, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i in np.nditer(contours):
    cnt = contours[i]

    rows,cols = img.shape[:2]
    [vx,vy,x,y] = cv2.fitLine(cnt, cv2.DIST_L2,0,0.01,0.01)
    lefty = int((-x*vy/vx) + y)
    righty = int(((cols-x)*vy/vx)+y)
    img = cv2.line(im,(cols-1,righty),(0,lefty),(0,242,255),3)

cv2.imshow("line", img)
```

I am honestly very new to OpenCV and numpy and have been working off of examples, I don't understand everything that is in my code much to my dissatisfaction. I think it is an issue with my usage of the numpy array but I can't seem to find how to do it properly.

Thanks

Comment: Won't simply `for cnt in contours:` work?

Comment: contours[i] does not simply work with a normal i as an integer it would seem, if I didn't need to call contours[i] it would work.

Comment: I think by default it has singleton dims. So, when you need to use `contours[i]`, squeeze it instead `np.squeeze(contours[i])`.

Comment: I still get the too many operands error

Comment: I meant using : `for cnt in contours:`. Then later on inside the loop, use `np.squeeze(cnt)` instead whereever you had `contours[i]`, but `cv2.fitLine()` might need `cnt` as it is without squeeze-ing.

Comment: When I try this I get "Python int too large to convert to C long".

Comment: Show us the traceback/ line causing it.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Codey\Desktop\Lab\Starry night\Testing\shapes1.py", line 45, in <module>
    img = cv2.line(im,(cols-1,righty),(0,lefty),(0,242,255),3)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Comment: Hmm, and we don't know what is `im`, which isn't clear from the posted code.

Comment: Sorry that is the original image

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any idea other that already discussed and pointed out earlier.

Comment: Thanks you anyways!

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if  `vy/vx` was close to a division-by-zero, which could lead to some huge integers (cc @Divakar).

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
# loop over the contours
for c in contours:
    # get bounding rect
   (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    # draw red rect
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```